# Reduce duplication - Create delegate from an instance method

Tags: c#

I am working with an existing, slightly complex relationship between objects. After some refactoring for the sake of understandability, my code now looks like this:

```
TemplateColorList colors = new TemplateColorList();
var template = new Template {
    TextElements = CreateTextElements(textElementData,
        /* -> */ (textElement, colorParam1, colorParam2) => colors.AddTextColor(textElement, colorParam1, colorParam2)
    ),
    ClipArtElements = CreateClipArtElements(clipArtElementData,
        /* -> */ (clipArtElement, colorParam) => colors.AddClipArtColor(clipArtElement, colorParam)
    ),
    Colors = colors,
};
```

I see duplication that I think can be removed, though - The delegates are just passing parameters as-is to `colors` methods. **Is there a way to create a delegate from an instance method (not static) without duplicating the parameters?**

Comment: Isn't it just `CreateTextElements( textElementData, colors.AddTextColor )` without this extra delegate?

Comment: You need delegates here, because `colors` needs to be captured in a closure. Since it's also passed as the `Colors` property, `Template` is slightly suspect in that it could be passing that as a parameter.

Comment: Like `ClipArtElements = CreateClipArtElements(clipArtElementData, colors.AddClipArtColor)`. If you've ever forgotten the parenthesis on a method call, you might have gotten a compiler error: `Cannot convert method group to something.` This is the opposite. Now you want to refer to the method without parenthesis or arguments because the method is the argument.

Comment: Ha, it would be that easy. Thanks so much @WiktorZychla, @ScottHannen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments into an answer...

"Isn't it just CreateTextElements( textElementData, colors.AddTextColor ) without this extra delegate?" - @WiktorZychla

"If you've ever forgotten the parenthesis on a method call, you might have gotten a compiler error: Cannot convert method group to something. This is the opposite. Now you want to **refer to the method without parenthesis or arguments** because the method is the argument." - @ScottHannen (emphasis mine)

Thanks for the help! I was wrongly making an assumption that the types wouldn't work out here. Taking their advice, my code now looks like:

```
TemplateColorList colors = new TemplateColorList();
var template = new Template {
    TextElements = CreateTextElements(textElementData, colors.AddTextColor),
    ClipArtElements = CreateClipArtElements(clipArtElementData, colors.AddClipArtColor),
    Colors = colors,
};
```